# Exception : Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting below exception:

Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

```
<annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ggk" />


    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/name" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="sa" />

    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.ggk.domain.Person</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hbmdl.auto">create</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="personDaoImpl" class="com.myorg.dao.PersonDaoImpl" >
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService" class="com.myorg.service.PersonServiceimpl">
        <beans:property name="personDaoImpl" ref="personDaoImpl"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myorg" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean> 



</beans:beans>
```

Dao Class

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.myorg.domain.Person;

public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /*public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }*/

    private Session session;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

    @Override
    public int addPerson(Person person) {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if(session!=null)
        session.persist(person);
        else 
        System.out.println("session is null");
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int updatePerson(Person person) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(person);
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int removePeron(List<Integer> personIds) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        int count = 0;
        for (Integer personId : personIds) {
            Person person = this.getPersonById(personId);
            if (person != null) {
                session.delete(person);
                System.out.println("Person deleted successfully with id :"
                        + personId);
                count++;
            } else {
                System.err.println("No peron found with id :" + personId);
            }

        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> getAllPerons() {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return session.createQuery("from Person").list();
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
    }

}
```

Adding setter method for sessionFactory in dao class resolves the issue, Howevere I am using @Autowire then Why should I add setter method? ... Can I execute without adding setter method?

Comment: Do not post images of code. Copy/paste the code into your question and format with the `{}` button (or indent 4 spaces)

Comment: Done, Thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: Your PersonDaoImpl is not annotated

Comment: You are wiring the `sessionFactory` in XML with a `property` element, this requires a setter.

Comment: @M. Deinum, Thanks and this is what I am expecting, Can you tell me if I Don't Want to use setter method then how can i Process?

Comment: Isn't that obvious... Don't set it in xml with `property` element.

Comment: Also you have 2 component-scan elements, just put them in a single one with a `,` separated list of packages. You don't need to add `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` as that is already implied by `context:component-scan` the same applies to `context:annotation-config`.